# Hard Drive not detected in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: hard-drive, bootloader

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS in this summer and all was going fine, but then my computer was switched off in the middle of loading the bios. When I boot, its not recognizing my hard drive in which I had installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I even tried to boot ubuntu from the live CD but then too its not recognizing the hard drive. And the BIOS is saying "no boot loader found".

Comment: I would remove the cables and re-connect them, or even try different sata/power cables. Also, try to power off the computer and unplug it from the power socket (leave it unplugged for 1-2 minutes). Can you provide a screenshot of ubuntu running "disk utility" from a live cd? Edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove the cables and re-connect them, or even try different sata/power cables.

Also, try to power off the computer and unplug it from the power socket (leave it unplugged for 1-2 minutes).

Can you provide a screenshot of ubuntu running "disk utility" from a live cd? Edit your question and add it.

Comment: I am also having this same problem. Even i tried with different sata and power cables. I am unable to see the hard disk using fdisk -l